# HTML5 and CSS3 tree menu with nice hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I would like to implement a tree menu like the link bellow using HTML5 and CSS3 or jquery menu or somehow using ordinary html, css and javascript .


http://www.crystal.ch/abb/power_systems_landscape/

You may notice that there is following issues involved,

1. Nice hover effect (I badly  need this)
2. Rotation of menu item arrow icon

Also here you see sliding up and down smoothly that is not problem to me.

Any idea or reference would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: any other link. the website is to heavy. so hard to load

Comment: ohh now loaded. i have same effect as this ill post my code to help you

Answer (score 5):

To start we need the HTML

```
<p class="menu_head">first</p>

    <div class="menu_body">
         <a href="">1</a>
            <a href="">2</a>
            <a href="">3</a>
           <a href="">4</a>
    </div>

  <p class="menu_head1">Second</p>

    <div class="menu_body">
         <a href="">1</a>

    </div>
```

Jquery for the effect

```
$("#firstpane p.menu_head").click(function()
{
    $(this).next("div.menu_body").slideToggle(300).siblings("div.menu_body").slideUp("slow");

});
$("#firstpane p.menu_head1").click(function()
{
    $(this).next("div.menu_body").slideToggle(300).siblings("div.menu_body").slideUp("slow");

});
    $("#firstpane p.menu_head").mouseover(function()
    {
    $(this).css("text-indent","35px");
    $(this).css("backgroundImage","url(images/trans.png)").fadeTo("slow",0.33);

});

$("#firstpane p.menu_head").mouseout(function()
{
    $(this).css("text-indent","10px");
    $(this).css("backgroundImage","url(images/headbot1.png)").fadeTo("slow", 1);    
});
```

I added the mouseover and mouseout for your glass effect. just create a background with white color or any color or just erase the .css can make it this way.

```
$(this).fadeTo("slow",0.33);
```

CSS

```
.menu_head {
    font-family: arial;font-weight: bold;
    font-size:10px;
    color: black;
    left:3%;
    height:7px;
    text-indent:10px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin:1px;
    font-weight:bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu_head1 {
    font-family: arial;font-weight: bold;
    font-size:10px;
    color: black;
    left:3%;
    height:7px;
    text-indent:10px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin:1px;
    font-weight:bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu_body {
    display:none;
}
.menu_body a{
    font-family: arial;font-weight: bold;
    left:3%;
    width: 220px;
    height:7px;
    text-indent:10px;
    position:relative;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display:block;
    color:#006699;
    padding-left:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

See [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TZQgZ/)

try to edit the css for it was made to adapt to my site.
Gudluck

Comment: you may missing firstpane wrapper div. anyway let me investigate, thanks

Comment: As per I test. you just show sliding up and down smoothly on click but I also badly need the hover glass effect like demo link that I mentioned

Comment: i see the glass effect when hover i think is also a css event using jquery with opacity. let me work with it and update you. i looked into the website and it was created in flash. lets se if we can replicate it in jquery

Comment: @shahdat i dont know if this effect will make the same effect as of the website you have given but it the least i can do. it has glass effect also just play aroung with the opacity or add a bg image on the button to achieve the effect. Have fun and Gudluck. hope it helped.

Comment: thanks for your attempt but we need a moveable effect on hover middle to both(left and right)